# pipenv or virtualenv , which one is better to use?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, virtualenv, pipenv

I am really frustrated by choosing which one to build my django projects on...
what are the cons and pros of each so that i can choose one.

on one hand some websites suggest using virtualenv , while on the other hand on quora some people suggest to use pipenv , some people say pipenv is not what the official site claims to be good, while other sites say this is the best ever way to build you'r django projects.

could you please help me get out of this headache ?

NOTE:**The reason why I am asking this question is because...there might be some advantages in either of them , that may make troubles in further development of web-apps according to my researches on different websites.**

This is the process of building a django project with pipenv :

```
pipenv install django==2.1

pipenv shell

django-admin startproject project .

python mange.py runserver  # check wether all things are alright or not.

#Ctrl+c #go out of the server

python mange.py startapp app #creat an app in your project

# Add your app in settings.py at project folder by finding Installed_apps 
variable containing a list
of installed apps like this and add another app url like 
this===>'app.apps.AppConfig'

#Then go to views.py in your project's app folder and do this

from django.http import HttpResponse

def homePageView(request):
return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')

#then make a urls.py in your project's app folder and type this in it

from django.urls import path
from .views import homePageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', homePageView, name = 'home')
         ]
#The come to urls.py in project folder and add include to the imported 
functions

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include#<== I mean this one

#Then add another path to urlpatterns containing a list

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('shipping.urls'))#<==I mean this one
  ]
```

This is the process for virtualenv:

```
python -m venv ll_env
ll_env\Scripts\activate
pip install django
django-admin startproject learning_log .
ython manage.py startapp learning_logs
```

but there is quite a many difference between them that makes me worry which one should be used.

Comment: use both - duplicate project and run one copy with `pipenv` and other copy with `virtualenv` and you will see which one you prefer.

Comment: @rdas I mentioned the code

Comment: @Khelwood, the code is mentioned

Comment: Refer to the following link. Apparently there have been irregularities with `pipenv`. It seems it may have been getting an unduly positive press: https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2018/07/17/pipenv-promises-a-lot-delivers-very-little/

Comment: This is the Chris Warrick conclusion: Pip, setup.py, and virtualenv — the traditional, tried-and-true tools — are still available, undergoing constant development. Using them can lead to a simpler, better experience. Also of note, tools like virtualenvwrapper can manage virtualenvs better than the aforementioned new Python tools, because it is based on shell scripts (which can modify the enivironment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/tool-recommendations/#application-dependency-management), python packing manager themself recommand using pipenv

```
Use Pipenv to manage library dependencies when developing Python applications. See Managing Application Dependencies for more details on using pipenv.

Consider other tools such as pip when pipenv does not meet your use case.
```

Comment: A really bad recommendation. Poetry is much better than pipenv. I've used pipenv for months and finally come to poetry.

Comment: @kawing-chiu the guy asked which one is better, i answered his question :)

Comment: "and finally come to poetry" why? I'm asking because I'm new to this stuff and don't want to spend months on a wrong choice... Meanwhile I'm a Kenneth Reitz fan, but that's off-topic ;-)